# Cannot sort without index mongo query

Tags: mongodb, exception, indexing

I have the following query:

```
{ "loc" : { "$near" : [ 32.08 , 34.779] , "$maxDistance" : 0.04499640028797696} , "isCreated" : true , "loc.venueName" :  null}
```

Sorted by :

```
{"lastActiveTime":-1}
```

Limited to 100 documents.

***loc*** - embedded document containing the keys ( lat,lon,venueName )

***isCreated*** - boolean

**lastActiveTime** - date

I am getting the exception:

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit;

I have tried all kind of variation of indexes, compound and not compound but i am still getting the above exception, tried...

```
{'loc':'2d', 'lastActiveTime':-1}
```

And:

```
{'lastActiveTime':-1}
```

Which indexes I need to create in the document in order for the query to succeed?

MongoDB version is 2.0.6

This is example document (with the relevant keys):

```
{
  "_id" : "5d5085601208aa918bea3c1ede31374d",
  "gender" : "female",
  "isCreated" : true,
  "lastActiveTime" : ISODate("2013-04-08T11:30:56.615Z"),
  "loc" : {
    "lat" : 32.082230499955806,
    "lon" : 34.813542940344945,
    "locTime" : NumberLong(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried, `{loc: '2d', isCreated: 1, loc.venueName: 1, lastActiveTime: -1}`?

Comment: Can you add an example document to your question? Just to make sure the query is appropriate to begin with.

Comment: example document added..in that document loc.venueName is null / not exist

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the index has not been created.  If you are sorting on `lastActiveTime` then that's the one to index.

Try veryfing that you have indexes set up properly by typing this in the mongo shell:

```
use yourdbname
db.yourcollectionname.getIndexes()
```

Comment: Do you mean that is the one to index besides the 2d index on the loc property, right? not compound..

Comment: Yes, lastActiveTime needs it's own index, not a compound index.

Comment: It is created....{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "lastActiveTime" : -1} , "ns" : "hazeDB.profile" , "name" : "lastActiveTime" , "dropDups" : false , "sparse" : false} Any thoughts?

Comment: MongoDB cannot use index intersectioning as of yet as such putting lastActiveTime on its own will be of no use and will make the index not be used.

Comment: so what are you suggesting? ho now i c... actually i think i tried that let me check again

Comment: Nop tried {loc: '2d', isCreated: 1, loc.venueName: 1, lastActiveTime: -1} not working either still the same exception...